# splitting string into array with delimiter occurring multiple times in a row

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
Beans,,,Beans,,,Beans,,,Beans,,,playstation,,,Cool Beans,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I am using this:

```
//split the string
String[] rowValues = row.split(",,,");
```

I expect that `rowValues` have length of `17`.

But in the above case the length is only 6. How do i deal with the `,,,` occurring multiple times in a row?

Comment: You should just split on ',' and then filter the array for strings of length 0.

Comment: this is not duplicate of that question @Pshemo if you use `.split(",{3}", -1);` you will get 17 and not 16 like the OP ask i suggest to reopen it again please

Comment: @YCF_L I assumed that this was just OPs miscalculation. Will reopen if OP will clarify his reasons for 16 vs 17 values.

Comment: yes it was a miscalculation on my part. I needed `17`

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `{3}` to indicate you want three of the character in your *regular expression*. Second, pass a negative *limit* to [`String.split(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) which the linked Javadoc notes *If `n` is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.* Like,

```
String[] rowValues = row.split(",{3}", -1);
```

which will return *17* values with your provided input; if you literally need 16 then you can specify that instead

```
String[] rowValues = row.split(",{3}", 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put after each three `,,,` a separator for example `,,,_` then split with this separator instead :

```
String row = "Beans,,,Beans,,,Beans,,,Beans,,,playstation,,,Cool "
    + "Beans,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,";
String[] list = Arrays.stream(row.replaceAll("(,,,)", "$1_").split("_"))
    .map(t -> t.replaceAll("(.+),{3}$", "$1"))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(list.length);//size = 16
```

Outputs

```
[Beans, Beans, Beans, Beans, playstation, Cool Beans, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,, ,,,]
```